# Error: identifier <uint8_t> undefined and is it possible to use at openCV

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, image-processing

Consider:

```
int cn = img_V.channels();
Scalar_<unit8_t> bgrPixel;

for (int i = 0; i < img_V.rows; i++)
{
    uint8_t* rowPtr = img_V.row(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < img_V.cols; j++)
    {
        bgrPixel.val[0] = rowPtr[j*cn + 0]; // B
        bgrPixel.val[1] = rowPtr[j*cn + 1]; // G
        bgrPixel.val[2] = rowPtr[j*cn + 2]; // R

        // Do something with BGR values...
    }
}
```

I am using Visual Studio and OpenCV, but it can't identify the `uint8_t` showing error. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why in the opposite order, *BGR*? Why not the standard order, [RGB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RGB_color_model)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen: That’s one of the many stupid things OpenCV does. It seems like an easy choice, storing RGB values in the right order, but no... :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add

```
#include <cstdint>
```

to *see* `uint8_t`.

Please note, however, in OpenCV you should use `uchar`.

---

Also please note that you're not looping correctly.
A correct approach would be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < img_V.rows; i++)
{
    Vec3b* rowPtr = img_V.ptr<Vec3b>(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < img_V.cols; j++)
    {
        Vec3b& bgrPixel = rowPtr[j];

        // Do something with BGR values...
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion of the library. :D but if I want to use your loop system then how can I display the pixel value? :)

Comment: `bgrPixel` will contain the values for each pixel. To display the value, you can just `cout << bgrPixel;` , or to access each channel: `cout << "B:" << int(bgrPixel[0]) << " G: " << int(bgrPixel[1]) << " R: " << int(bgrPixel[2]);`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what I wanted :)

Answer (score 0):

Since you are probably dealing with an image, I imagine that `img_V` is a `cv::Mat`. According to the most recent [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#acce30f9c4475038ee86ea8b24e00850a&gsc.tab=0), `cv::Mat::row(int y)` returns another `cv::Mat`. But there isn't any default conversion to `uint8_t` or  `uchar`.

However, if you want to get a *pointer* to a specific row of the image, you should use `cv::Mat::ptr(int i0)`, which returns a `uchar *`, or any other type pointer if you use its template version.

But you want a uint8_t pointer, you first need to do as Miki says, and `#include <csdtint>`.